# Can not open devtools

Tags: nativescript

I can not open chrome dev-tools by url when using nativescript via angular:

[chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/inspector.html?experiments=true&ws=localhost:40000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ff0B6.png)

[But when copied the link and paste to google chrome, the result is just search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvVNY.png)

I tried to reinstall google chrome. Delete node_modules folder, package-lock file, and reinstall npm. But can't resolve problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Chrome 83 broke the devtools url. There's a fix to the NativeScript CLI in [6.7.4](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/releases/tag/v6.7.4) but in the meantime you can just use this url instead:

```
devtools://devtools/bundled/inspector.html?ws=localhost:40000
```